# English language Beauty and the Beast trailer were Lumiere speaks French at the end with the last two words being Mon Chéri

Tags: france

I remember that there was this advertisement and trailer on TV for an anniversary or special edition DVD on Blu-Ray for the Walt Disney 1991 film Beauty and the Beast! I remember that Lumiere speaks French at the end with the last two words being Mon Chéri but I don't remember what anniversary or special edition it was!

What Lumière says in French in the advertisement and trailer is not the same thing that Lumière says in French in the film!

Comment: I suggest asking at Movies Stack Exchange https://movies.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not related to the French language or finer points of usage.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was responded to so negatively.  Anyway, it would be good to have the link.

Comment: Peut-être : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JW5pX-baVdA

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not a question [about the finer points of the French language](https://french.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

Based on Luke Sawczak's link, Lumière says:

> Enchanté, chérie

Which means "*Nice to meet you, darling*".

Comment: It's good to know what Lumière says on Luke Sawczak's link except that I didn't think of mentioning that what Lumière says in French in the advertisement and trailer is not the same thing that Lumière says in French in the film!

Comment: @AnaMaria Well, how about you give us the link?

Comment: I don't remember what anniversary or special edition it was! That's why I'm asking this question! Hopefully someone will provide us with a correct link!

Comment: @AnaMaria we likely don't have the expertise to know what trailer/advertistment has the different dialogue, but as Luke suggested, maybe they would know on Movies.SE ; feel free to update your question if you get a link. i'm curious about this, too, given that Beauty and the Beast used to be one of my favourite Disney movies!

Comment: @silph Sadly they instantly closed her question over there, God knows why :( I would've thought it was right up their alley...

Comment: @LukeSawczak I think since most of the question is finding the correct trailer (the French part is trivial), it belongs on movie.SE rather than here.

Comment: They closed my question because they no longer support identification questions as  they discontinued support for these questions which is beyond me!